# Trying to build custom debian iso using live-build but have a error

Tags: linux, debian

> - sudo lb build [2022-07-24 14:38:27] lb build  P: live-build    1:20190311 P: Building config tree for a debian/bullseye/amd64 system
>   [2022-07-24 14:38:27] lb bootstrap  P: Setting up cleanup function
>   [2022-07-24 14:38:28] lb bootstrap_cache restore P: Restoring
>   bootstrap stage from cache... [2022-07-24 14:38:28] lb
>   bootstrap_debootstrap  P: Begin bootstrapping system... W: skipping
>   bootstrap, already done [2022-07-24 14:38:28] lb bootstrap_cache save
>   P: Saving bootstrap stage to cache... W: skipping
>   bootstrap_cache.save, already done [2022-07-24 14:38:28] lb
>   chroot_devpts install P: Begin mounting /dev/pts... [2022-07-24
>   14:38:28] lb chroot_proc install P: Begin mounting /proc...
>   [2022-07-24 14:38:28] lb chroot_selinuxfs install [2022-07-24
>   14:38:28] lb chroot_sysfs install P: Begin mounting /sys...
>   [2022-07-24 14:38:28] lb chroot_debianchroot install P: Configuring
>   file /etc/debian_chroot /usr/lib/live/build/chroot_debianchroot:
>   рядок 50: chroot/etc/debian_chroot: Немає такого файла або каталогу
>   P: Begin unmounting filesystems... P: Saving caches... chroot: failed
>   to run command ‘/usr/bin/env’: No such file or directory

Comment: It means you did not install the dependencies live-build needs.

Comment: @stark but when i build debian 10 buster iso it succeeds